# Is this sentence grammatically correct and makes sense?

Tags: usage, phrase, grammaticality

```
Ich freue mich auf ins Kino gehen.
```

I wrote the sentence above myself from an example in Duolingo and it was like this:

```
Ich freue mich auf Amerika
```

But when I translated it from English the sentence I wanted, it translated like this:

```
Ich freue mich darauf, ins Kino zu gehen.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <strike>Ich freue mich auf ins Kino gehen.</strike>

Prepositions lead noun phrases, not verb phrases. You can make a verb a noun by nominalizing the infinitive for example:

> Ich freue mich auf **das Gehen ins Kino.**

This is grammatical but it sounds clunky in this example. That is mostly because of the appended direction. In colloquial German, people may say:

> Ich freue mich auf **das ins-Kino-Gehen.**

But that's still a bit odd. A better way to phrase it is:

> Ich freue mich auf **den Kinobesuch.**

which combines the nouns *das Kino* and *der Besuch* on the fly. German native speakers do that all the time. Do it as well.

If you are lazy, you could also say:

> Ich freu' mich auf's Kino.

Here the listener has to guess from context that this is about going to the movies. This is also a very common way to phrase such things in German. That's why Duolingo has it with *Amerika*.

---

> Ich freue mich darauf, ins Kino zu gehen.

This is an alternative that retains the verb phrase in an adverbial clause. You need to put the *da*-adverb with the matching preposition into the main clause for this.

But it sounds very formal. People don't speak like this.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is comprehensible (I understand what you want to say), but it is not grammatical. You can't put an infinitive phrase after a preposition this way.

"darauf, ins Kino zu gehen" is of course ok and the way that native speakers would say it.

You can also *maybe* say "Ich freue mich aufs (= auf das) Ins-Kino-Gehen" (turning the verbal phrase into a noun phrase). This is a very clumsy way to say it, but it is grammatical.